# Failed to download a platform extension: System.Windows.Data.zip in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

We are running a silverlight asp.net appliction and we get the following error:

Line: 64
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2152
Category: InitializeError
Message: Failed to download a platform extension: System.Windows.Data.zip

What do I need to do to fix this??

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to turn off the "Reduce XAP size by using application library caching" option in order to run the app as standalone.